# Laurent series and tensor

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

Let us begin with the complex vector space 
\begin{equation}
V_{z}=\Big\{\omega\in \mathbb{C}[[z,z^{-1}]]dz\  \mid \operatorname{Res}_{z=0}  \omega (z)\Big\}
\end{equation}

We could define the tensor product of $V_{z_1} \otimes V_{z_2}$.

My question is why $$\omega_{0,2}:= \frac{dz_1\ dz_2}{(z_1 - z_2)^2}$$ does not belong to $V_{z_1} \otimes V_{z_2}$.

Residue of $\omega_{0,2}$ at $z_1 =0 , z_2 =0 $ is zero. What is going here?

Answer (score 1):

The tensor product consists of elements
$$f(z_1)g(z_2)\,dz_1\,dz_2$$
where $f$ and $g$ are Laurent series satisfying your residue condition.
But
$$h(z_1,z_2)=\frac1{(z_1-z_2)^2}$$
cannot be written as a product of a Laurent series in $z_1$ and
a Laurent series in $z_2$. Nothing mysterious about that; most functions
of two variables are not products of two functions of one variable.

Comment: Is this obvious in this case it can't be written? Is there some proof?

Comment: For an $h$ to have a such a  factorisation one needs $f(z_1,z_2)f(z_1',z_2')=f(z_1,z_2')f(z_1',z_2)$ etc.